# get missing attributes in XML from XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

how I can check if an attribute or an element is missing in my xml, when I deserialize an Object from Xml?

[XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) fill missing values with their defaults, but how I can know whether it is the default value or it's missing in the Xml?

I have to know this, because if I publish a new version of my program and have added values to my objects, I want to show a prompt with new (missing) values to the user. He have to know the circumstances.

```
[Serializable]
public class Dummy
{
    public int MyInteger { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public double MyDouble { get; set; }
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }
    public Dummy()
    {
        //Missing values in the xml would filled up with these values
        MyInteger = default(int);
        MyString = default(string);
        MyDouble = default(double);
        MyBool = default(bool);
    }
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dummy));
        Dummy dummy = new Dummy(){ MyInteger = 1, MyBool = false, MyDouble = 3.4, MyString="dummy"};

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using(StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
            serializer.Serialize(writer, dummy);
        /*sb contains:
         *  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
         *  <Dummy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         *      <MyInteger>1</MyInteger>
         *      <MyString>dummy</MyString>
         *      <MyDouble>3.4</MyDouble>
         *      <MyBool>false</MyBool>
         *  </Dummy>
         */

        //xml without MyDouble
        string xml = @" <Dummy>
                    <MyInteger>1</MyInteger>
                    <MyString>dummy</MyString>
                    <MyBool>false</MyBool>
                </Dummy>";
        Dummy readDummy;
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            readDummy = (Dummy)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        /*readDummy contains:
         * MyInteger = 1,
         * MyString = "dummy",
         * MyDouble = 0,
         * MyBool = false
         */
    }
}
```

### Update

Thank you [Yeldar Kurmangaliyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218692) for the Schema-Validation.
My current Problem is that the exception which was thrown by the Schema-Validator let me access only MyBool and not the missing value MyDouble.
The Exception-Message contains the name of the property MyDouble, but should I extract the property name from the Exception-Message? It feels very dirty.

Here is the updated code:

```
[Serializable]
public class Dummy
{
    public int MyInteger { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public double MyDouble { get; set; }
    public bool MyBool { get; set; }
    public Dummy()
    {
        //Missing values in the xml would filled up with these values
        MyInteger = default(int);
        MyString = default(string);
        MyDouble = default(double);
        MyBool = default(bool);
    }
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dummy));
        string xml = @" <Dummy>
            <MyInteger>1</MyInteger>
            <MyString>dummy</MyString>
            <MyBool>false</MyBool>
        </Dummy>";
        Dummy readDummy;


        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings() { ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema };
        settings.Schemas.Add(GetXmlSchemas(typeof(Dummy)).First());
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += (s, e) =>
        {
            //I got an exception with the sender "MyBool". How I can reach the variable "MyDouble" which is missing?
        };

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
            readDummy = (Dummy)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
    public static XmlSchemas GetXmlSchemas(Type type)
    {
        var schemas = new XmlSchemas();
        var exporter = new XmlSchemaExporter(schemas);
        var mapping = new XmlReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(type);
        exporter.ExportTypeMapping(mapping);
        return schemas;
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you expecting to generate a `xml` without `MyDouble`?

Comment: The Xml was generated in an older version of the program, where MyDouble doesn't exists. In the new version I added MyDouble, but it doesn't exist in the old xml file. Or just go assume that a user has deleted an element from the XML file.

Comment: making the element `Nullable` should not include a default value during `Deserialization`.

Comment: What do you mean with "making the element Nullable"? If I change the definition of `MyDouble` to `double? MyDouble` has no effect. Default values (in the constructor) are neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XmlReaderSettings` class for initializing and using `XmlReader` over a `StringReader`. However, you will need an XSD schema. 
That's a proper way to validate XML on deserializing.
Take a look at XmlReaderSettings. Maybe, you will find an easier way to do this :)

```
string xml = @" <Dummy>
                <MyInteger>1</MyInteger>
                <MyString>dummy</MyString>
                <MyBool>false</MyBool>
            </Dummy>";
Dummy readDummy;

XmlSchemaSet schemas = null; // here is your schema
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Schemas.Add(schemas);
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += (s, e) =>
{
    throw e.Exception; // Here you go
};

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
   using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
       readDummy = (Dummy)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question, maybe you have a solution to my Problem to accessing the property-name "MyDouble"?